# Is there any speed difference between the following two cases?

Tags: c++, performance

Will judge_function_2 be faster than judge_function_1? I think judge_function_1's AND statement needs to judge two, while judge_function_2 only needs to be judged once.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool judge_function_1()
{
    if(100 == 100 || 100 == 200)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool judge_function_2()
{
    if(100 == 100)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(100 == 200)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cout << judge_function_1() << endl;
    cout << judge_function_2() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your thinking is wrong in the modern world of optimising compilers. You aren't describing assembly, you are describing behavior. Any modern compiler will easily optimise both to `return true;`

Comment: Look at the output of your compiler; you'll see both cases are optimized entirely to a static value of `true`. No comparisons are made at runtime.

Comment: When you have a bool function with `if (<condition>) return true; return false;` you can just do `return <condition>;`.

Comment: I think you've missed the fact that `||` is "short-circuiting". Read about it in your favourite C++ book. And you should, of course, write `return 100 == 100 || 100 == 200;` rather than any of these.

Comment: Don't underestimate what a compiler can spot and optimize, and this is about as easy for a compiler as it gets.  [CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4).

Answer (score 6):

Using godbolt and compiling with gcc with optimizations enabled results in the following assembly code https://godbolt.org/z/YEfYGv5vh :

```
judge_function_1():
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
judge_function_2():
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

The functions assembly code is identical and both return true, they will be exactly the same fast.

Comment: Moreover, if the functions are in the same translation unit as the calling code, they will almost certainly be removed by inlining/constant folding and never called at all.

Comment: It is worth pointing out "as-if rule". So compiler can perform any transformation of code as log as visible effects of execution remains unchanged. This is the reason code for both cases here is identical.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers know how to read and understand code. They cannot guess your intentions, but thats only an issue when your code does not express your intentions.

A compiler "knows" that `100 == 100` is always `true`. It cannot be something else.

A compiler "knows" that `true || whatever` is always `true`. It cannot be something else.

A compiler "knows" that after a `return` no other statements are executed in a function.

The transformations are straightforward to proove that both functions are equivalent to

```
void same_thing_just_with_less_fluff() { return true; }
```

The code in both functions is just a very complicated way to say `return true;` / "this function returns true".

Compilers optimize code when you ask them to. If you turn on optimizations there is no reason to expect any difference between the two functions. Calling them has exactly the same effect. There is no observable difference between the two. And as shown above, the way to proove this is rather simple. It is somewhat safe to assume that any compiler can optimize the two functions to simply `return true;`.

---

To my experience, a misunderstanding that is common among beginners is that your code would be instructions for your CPU. That when you write `100 == 100` then at runtime there must be `100` in one register and `100` in another register and the cpu needs to carry out an operation to check if the values are the same. This picture is totally wrong.

Your code is an abstract description of the observable behavior of your code. Its a compilers job to translate this abstract description into something your cpu understands and can execute to exhibit the observable behavior you described in your code in accordance with the definitions provided by the C++ standard.

What your code describes is in plain english: Write `1` followed by a newline to stdout and then flush it twice.

Answer (score 1):

From your guess:

> I think judge_function_1's AND statement needs to judge two, while judge_function_2 only needs to be judged once.

I deduce that there ARE some compare performed, like if you pass two parameters to your function and compare them with some constant:

```
bool judge_function_1(int x, int y)
{
  if(x == 100 || y == 200)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Even in that case, if the first condition is `true`, the function will return immediately, without comparing `y` to `200`.